# How would you do a find on two different models and sort both in one array by created_at column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So for example ...
Lets say I have a Posts model and a News model, that are essentially the same thing (structure wise)
columns are
* title
* content
* createdat
* updatedat

The client has requested showing both news and Posts on the same page interleaved and sorted by created_at date ...
Does anyone know how I would go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Post.all + News.all).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: I want to be like you when I grow up.

Comment: (Post.all + News.all).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse to have it sort with the latest items first ... just in case anyone else is following this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning, cwninja's answer will be really slow with large datasets because it requires pulling ALL of the members out of the database and then running a sort on them.

I would rarely suggest raw SQL, but in this case I can't think of a better way.