# How can I sort two different models with different attributes by created_at with postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting

I have a Videos model and a News model. I want to paginate these in a feed and interleave them by their `created_at` date.

I considered creating a Feed model and adding a `feed_id` to both the Videos and News model but I am unsure of how I would iterate through the attributes. I cannot call `feed.title` or `feed.content` because those attributes are located in the News and Video models.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654153/how-would-you-do-a-find-on-two-different-models-and-sort-both-in-one-array-by-cr) suggests `(Video.all + News.all).sort_by(&:created_at)` which can be [iterated through like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142227/iterating-sorting-results-from-two-different-models-with-different-attributes) however another user suggests:

> Just a warning, cwninja's answer will be really slow with large datasets because it requires pulling ALL of the members out of the database and then running a sort on them. 
>  
> I would rarely suggest raw SQL, but in this case I can't think of a better way.

I am using a Postgres database.

Comment: Same impasse here. So far my only option is to use plain SQL and ignore Rails completely, which goes against all better judgement.

Comment: In above question I suggest my approach to solve similar issue